# can not execute LIMIT on sql Developer

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

I am trying to execute following on sqlDeveloper

```
SELECT salary FROM emp ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 4, 1;
```

But it is throwing following error:

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 44

Comment: As an aside, if you find any answers to your questions useful, it's polite to mark them as accepted. See this link http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle 11g doesn't support the `LIMIT` clause, though the impending 12c release is rumored to support it.

Anyway, you can do this using an analytic windowing function:

```
select * from
( 
  select salary, row_number() over (order by salary desc) as rn
  from emp
)
where rn = 4;
```

You can also do this using `rownum`, but I find the above way to look cleaner.

Example [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3662/13) for you to mess around with.

Comment: Thanks Phil for your answer. but can you please tell me tell till which version of oracle LIMIT is supported ?

Comment: It's not supported. It is rumored to be supported in version 12c, which isn't released yet.